# Crosscompiling for ARM9 in Linux

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I am always using this procedure to cross compile programs for ARM926ej-s on my Arch Linux machine:

**1st** I compile the assembly source files using:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -ooutput_as.o input_as.s
```

**2nd** I compile C source files using:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -mno-thumb-interwork -mapcs-frame -mno-sched-prolog -fno-hosted -O3 -gdwarf-2 -ooutput_c.o input_c.c
```

**3rd** I link those to get an executable elf file `executable`:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -Tlinker_script.ld -oexecutable output_as.o output_c.o
```

**4th** I convert elf into binary using:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Ielf32-littlearm -Obinary --strip-all --verbose executable executable_bin
```

**5th** I prepare the binary for the USB-DFU transfer using application [unsimgcr](http://www.lpclinux.com/Downloads/WebHome) - this application somehow prepares the format to be uploaded to ARM microprocessors:

```
unsimgcr -pd executable_bin executable_bin_usb
```

---

And then i usualy upload the prepared program `executable_bin_usb` to the ARM926ej-s using application [dfu-util](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=dfu-util) like this:

```
sudo dfu-util -R -t2048 -Dexecutable_bin_usb
```

---

For some reason when in step **5** when I use unsimgcr i get this error:

```
[ziga@ziga-cq56 test]$ unsimgcr -pd executable_bin executable_bin_usbLPC3130/31/41/52 Un-Secure Image Creator Utility v1.1

Opening executable_bin
Incompatible file size!
```

Does anyone have any clue what i might be doing wrong or what is wrong in my program which is just a basic test program - here are all the source files which I got [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/) (this toolchain works for other programs):

**input_as.s**

```
.section INTERRUPT_VECTOR, "x"
.global _Reset
_Reset:
  B Reset_Handler
  B . 
  B .
  B .
  B .
  B .
  B .
  B .

Reset_Handler:
  LDR sp, =stack_top
  BL c_entry
  B .
```

**input_c.c**

```
int c_entry() {
  return 0;
}
```

**linker_script.ld**

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x11029000;
 .text : {
 startup.o (INTERRUPT_VECTOR)
 *(.text)
 }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss) }
 . = . + 0x1000;
 stack_top = .;
}
```

In linker script we set the entry point at location `0x11029000` which is needed in ARM, but i have no idea why would the size of my program be incompatible... Does anyone have any clue?

If I use the command `arm-none-eabi-readelf -a executable`to get some info about my elf file `executable` i get this info. It might come handy:

```
[ziga@ziga-cq56 test]$ arm-none-eabi-readelf -a executable
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x11029000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4716 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         14
  Section header string table index: 11

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        11029000 001000 000038 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 001038 000030 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 001068 00002a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 4] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 001092 000034 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 0010c6 000044 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 00110a 000035 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS        00000000 00113f 00001e 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 00115d 000020 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 00117d 000034 01  MS  0   0  1
  [10] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 0011b4 000020 00      0   0  4
  [11] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0011d4 000097 00      0   0  1
  [12] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00149c 000140 10     13  17  4
  [13] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0015dc 000035 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x11028000 0x11028000 0x01038 0x01038 R E 0x8000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

There are no unwind sections in this file.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 20 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 11029000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     8: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
     9: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    10: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    11: 11029020     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 Reset_Handler
    12: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    13: 1102902c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    14: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.c
    15: 11029030     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    16: 00000010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 $d
    17: 11029538     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS stack_top
    18: 11029030     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 c_entry
    19: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Reset

No version information found in this file.
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM926EJ-S"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TEJ
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: small
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

Comment: How big is your file ? unsimgcr has, for a reason I don't know, a max size of 128K for the file.

Comment: Max size of 128K is because of a memory limitations of ARM926ej-s. To check size i just right clicked them and looked at their sizes which are: executable (5.6kB), executable_bin (56b) and executable_bin_usb (0b... as the unsimgcr fails). Sizes are small, because if you look at the source files they are almost empty...

Comment: Well, the unsimgcr tool also have a minimum size. It may look like you're supposed to supply some kind of header - though it's hard to tell, I can't find any documentation for the tool.

Comment: Well the description of the header needed is described in the LPC3141 user manual: http://ziga-lausegger.netau.net/download/univerza/diploma/download/codebench_lite.tar.bz2 Look at the pages 89 and 92-94.

Comment: I solved this by adding a header. IF anyone needs the solution you can contact me.